# jquery validation по паттерну

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация

Хочу применить к полю проверку через паттерн. Что то вроде такого:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#registration-form").validate({

   rules:{
        login:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 10,
            regexp: '[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]{5,10}'
        },
   },

   messages: {
       login: {
           regexp: 'Username are 5-10 characters'
       }
   }       
 });
});
```

Но такой способ не работает. Как можно сделать проверку по паттерну? 
(Без PHP)

Comment: Ох уж эти [tag:жуквери-плюгины]... Что не работает-то?

Comment: regexp: '[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]{5,10}' это выражение и не работает

Comment: Ладно, перефразирую: Какая ошибка? Что не работает или работает в виде "выкину ошибку"? Какой текст ошибки, если есть?

Comment: Никакой ошибки не "выкидывает". Просто пропускает все не соответствующие паттерну выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.validator.addMethod('username', function(value, element) {
        return value.match(new RegExp("^" + "[A-Za-zа-яА-я]{5,10}" + "$"));
      }, 'Username are 5-10 characters.')

$("#registration-form").validate({

 rules:{
    login:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 10,
        username: true
    },
  }     
});
});
```

Comment: Секретная техника великого колдунства вуду - регулярка будет работать и без конструктора: `match(/^[A-Za-zа-яА-я]{5,10}$/)`. И лучше использовать тут `RegExp.prototype.test`.